# Python lxml - How to remove empty repeated tags

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have some XML that is generated by a script that may or may not have empty elements. I was told that now we cannot have empty elements in the XML. Here is an example:

```
<customer>  
    <govId>
       <id>@</id>
       <idType>SSN</idType>
           <issueDate/>
           <expireDate/>
           <dob/>
           <state/>
           <county/>
           <country/>
    </govId>
    <govId>
        <id/>
        <idType/>
        <issueDate/>
        <expireDate/>
        <dob/>
        <state/>
        <county/>
        <country/>
    </govId>
</customer>
```

The output should look like this:

```
<customer>  
    <govId>
       <id>@</id>
       <idType>SSN</idType>        
    </govId>        
</customer>
```

I need to remove all the empty elements. You'll note that my code took out the empty stuff in the "govId" sub-element, but didn't take out anything in the second. I am using lxml.objectify at the moment.

Here is basically what I am doing:

```
root = objectify.fromstring(xml)
for customer in root.customers.iterchildren():
    for e in customer.govId.iterchildren():
        if not e.text:
            customer.govId.remove(e)
```

Does anyone know of a way to do this with lxml objectify or is there an easier way period? I would also like to remove the second "govId" element in its entirety if all its elements are empty.

Comment: You say "*You'll note that my code took out the empty stuff in the "govId" sub-element, but didn't take out anything in the second.*" What "empty stuff" are you referring to? I'm confused; is the XML that you show the input or the output?

Comment: @mzjn I was also confused by that. I think it's the output he already got, but isn't right yet.

Comment: @mzjn - I was referring to the empty elements. I'm supposed to remove any empty elements I find. I just updated it to show the input and the output. I'd put in the entire example, but I'm not allowed to due to privacy concerns and the fact that the real XML is hundreds of lines long.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, the problem with your code is that you are iterating over `customers`, but not over `govIds`. On the third line you take the *first* `govId` for every customer, and iterate over its children. So, you'd need a another `for` loop for the code to work like you intended it to.

This small sentence at the end of your question then makes the problem quite a bit more complex: *I would also like to remove the second "govId" element in its entirety if all its elements are empty.*

This means, unless you want to hard code just checking one level of nesting, you need to **recursively** check if an element and it's children are empty. Like this for example:

```or-tag
def recursively_empty(e):
   if e.text:
       return False
   return all((recursively_empty(c) for c in e.iterchildren()))
```

**Note**: Python 2.5+ because of the use of the [`all()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#all).

You then can change your code to something like this to remove all the elements in the document that are empty all the way down.

```or-tag
# Walk over all elements in the tree and remove all
# nodes that are recursively empty
context = etree.iterwalk(root)
for action, elem in context:
    parent = elem.getparent()
    if recursively_empty(elem):
        parent.remove(elem)
```

Sample output:

```xml
<customer>
  <govId>
    <id>@</id>
    <idType>SSN</idType>
  </govId>
</customer>
```

One thing you might want to do is refine the condition `if e.text:` in the recursive function. Currently this will consider `None` and the empty string as empty, but not whitespace like spaces and newlines. Use [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string.strip) if that's part of your definition of "empty".

---

**Edit**: As pointed out by @Dave, the recursive function could be improved by using a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```or-tag
return all((recursively_empty(c) for c in e.getchildren()))
```

This will not evaluate `recursively_empty(c)` for all the children at once, but evaluate it for each one lazily. Since `all()` will stop iteration upon the first `False` element, this could mean a significant performance improvement.

**Edit 2**: The expression can be further optimized by using `e.iterchildren()` instead of `e.getchildren()`. This works with the [lxml etree API](http://lxml.de/api.html) and the [objectify API](http://lxml.de/objectify.html).

Comment: I didn't think that looked quite right. I don't actually see you using the any() builtin though, so I'm guessing you meant the all() builtin. I'm aware of the str.strip() part, but this data should already be stripped. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Mike Oops, of course I meant `all` (and that's what I used in the code and linked to), thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: When I run the for loop on my code, it does indeed remove the entire govId section when its empty, but if there is one or two elements in it that have data, it leaves those in plus all the empty ones too.

Comment: @Mike Ah, I thought that's what it's supposed to do? You said _I would also like to remove the second "govId" element in its entirety if all its elements are empty._ So I assumed if it's not empty, it should stay untouched.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing. My client's demands keep changing. They want ALL empty tags gone and if the element has all its sub-elements empty, than the whole element should be removed. I apologize for not making that clearer.

Comment: @Mike Ok, got it. Could you please update your question with some sample XML with 3 govId subelements that cover all cases that need to be handled, and add the output XML you need from that?

Comment: @Mike Updated my answer to remove **all** the empty elements in the whole tree.

Comment: Thanks! That works and it cleans up a bunch of my code to boot.

Comment: Can the list comprehension argument to `all()` be omitted?  That creates the entire list, while a generator expression `return all(recursively_empty(c) for c in e.getchildren())` (same as above, but without the square brackets) would lazily evaluate c one at a time.

Comment: @Dave Good catch! For the generator expression to work you'd need to add an additional pair of parens (they're part of the generator expression): `return all((recursively_empty(c) for c in e.getchildren()))`. The performance and memory improvement could be quite significant, since `all()` will stop iteration upon the first `False` element.

Comment: Per http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions, the parens can be omitted for single-argument calls.  :-)

Comment: @Dave then something like `x = y for y in [1,2,3]` should work. But it doesn't (invalid syntax). Somehow I don't exactly understand how to read that note in the reference.

Comment: not remove whole tag`<div class="clear"></div>`,   left `<div class="clear">`