# Using a .py script that cleans then splits a large MODS XML record to do the same for a Dublin Core XML record and I'm getting no output

Tags: python, xml

I took an OpenRefine template for translating a csv to a giant MODS XML record, then a .py script for cleaning it and turning it into several smaller xml files, named using one of the tags.  It works perfectly.  However, when I tried altering it to fit my needs for Dublin Core xml records... not so much.

I've got an OpenRefine template that gives me this from my csv:

```
<collection xmlns:xsi="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<record xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dctype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dc.xsd http://purl.org/dc/terms/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcterms.xsd http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcmitype.xsd http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/qualifieddc.xsd">

    <dc:title>[Mary Adams at the organ]</dc:title>
    <dc:creator>MacAfee, Don</dc:creator>


    <dc:date>4/14/1964</dc:date>
    <dc:subject>organs</dc:subject><dc:subject>musical instruments</dc:subject><dc:subject>musicians</dc:subject><dc:subject>Adams, Mary</dc:subject>
    <dc:description>Music instructor Mary C. Adams playing the organ.</dc:description>


    <dc:format>1 print : b&amp;w ; 6.5 x 6.5 in.</dc:format>


    <dcterms:spatial>Alexandria, Virginia</dcterms:spatial>

    <dc:type>Photograph</dc:type>
    <dc:format>Image</dc:format>


    <dc:identifier>MS332-01-01-001</dc:identifier>
    <dc:rights>Copyright has not been assigned to the Alexandria Library. All requests for permission to publish or quote from manuscripts must be submitted in writing to the Alexandria Library. Permission for publication is given on behalf of the Alexandria Library as the owner of the physical items and is not intended to include or imply permission of the copyright holder, which must also be obtained by the researcher.</dc:rights>

</record>
<record xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dctype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dc.xsd http://purl.org/dc/terms/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcterms.xsd http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcmitype.xsd http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/qualifieddc.xsd">

    <dc:title>[Portrait of Dr. Robert Adeson]</dc:title>



    <dc:date>1980</dc:date>
    <dc:subject>physicians</dc:subject><dc:subject>doctors</dc:subject><dc:subject>Adeson, Robert, M.D.</dc:subject>
    <dc:description>Dr. Robert L. Adeson, Alexandria Hospital.</dc:description>


    <dc:format>1 print : b&amp;w ; 5 x 7 in.</dc:format>


    <dcterms:spatial>Alexandria, Virginia</dcterms:spatial>

    <dc:type>Photograph</dc:type>
    <dc:format>Image</dc:format>


    <dc:identifier>MS332-01-01-002</dc:identifier>
    <dc:rights>Copyright has not been assigned to the Alexandria Library. All requests for permission to publish or quote from manuscripts must be submitted in writing to the Alexandria Library. Permission for publication is given on behalf of the Alexandria Library as the owner of the physical items and is not intended to include or imply permission of the copyright holder, which must also be obtained by the researcher.</dc:rights>

</record>
</collection>
```

I've got a Python program that cleans and separates a MODS record, that I've modified that looks like this:

```
import os, lxml.etree as ET

output_path = 'C:\\Users\\Staff\\Desktop\\Metadata\\SplitXML\\'

# parse source.xml with lxml
tree = ET.parse('source.xml')

# start cleanup
# remove any element tails
for element in tree.iter():
    element.tail = None

# remove any line breaks or tabs in element text
    if element.text:
        if '\n' in element.text:
            element.text = element.text.replace('\n', '') 
        if '\t' in element.text:
            element.text = element.text.replace('\t', '')

# remove any remaining whitespace
parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, remove_comments=True, recover=True)
treestring = ET.tostring(tree)
clean = ET.XML(treestring, parser)

# remove recursively empty nodes
def recursively_empty(e):
   if e.text:
       return False
   return all((recursively_empty(c) for c in e.iterchildren()))

context = ET.iterwalk(clean)
for action, elem in context:
    parent = elem.getparent()
    if recursively_empty(elem):
        parent.remove(elem)

# remove nodes with blank attribute
for element in clean.xpath(".//*[@*='']"):
    element.getparent().remove(element)

# remove nodes with attribute "null"
for element in clean.xpath(".//*[@*='null']"):
    element.getparent().remove(element)

# finished cleanup
# write out to intermediate file
with open('clean.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(clean))
print("XML is now clean")

# parse the clean xml
cleanxml = ET.iterparse('clean.xml', events=('end', ))

# find the <dc> nodes
for event, elem in cleanxml:
    if elem.tag == '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}record':

# name new files using the <dc:identifier> tag
        identifier = elem.find('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}dc:identifier').text
        filename = format(identifier + "_DC.xml")

        # write out to new file
        with open(output_path+filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem, pretty_print = True))
        print("Writing", filename)

# remove the intermediate file
os.remove('clean.xml')
print("All done!")
```

The cmd prints the "XML is now clean" and "All done!" statements, HOWEVER, there are no files in the SplitXML directory (or anywhere).  My attempt at de-bugging was to comment out the `os.remove('clean.xml')` line so I could look at the cleaned xml.  I've done this with the MODS .py script, and the xml file looks like what you'd expect.  However, the clean.xml file on the DC one is clean, but just one long string of code, rather than using different lines and tabs, like this:

```
<collection xmlns:xsi="http:www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><record xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dctype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dc.xsd http://purl.org/dc/terms/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcterms.xsd http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcmitype.xsd http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/qualifieddc.xsd"><dc:title>[Mary Adams at the organ]</dc:title><dc:creator>MacAfee, Don</dc:creator><dc:date>4/14/1964</dc:date><dc:subject>organs</dc:subject><dc:subject>musical instruments</dc:subject><dc:subject>musicians</dc:subject><dc:subject>Adams, Mary</dc:subject><dc:description>Music instructor Mary C. Adams playing the organ.</dc:description><dc:format>1 print : b&amp;w ; 6.5 x 6.5 in.</dc:format><dcterms:spatial>Alexandria, Virginia</dcterms:spatial><dc:type>Photograph</dc:type><dc:format>Image</dc:format><dc:identifier>MS332-01-01-001</dc:identifier><dc:rights>Copyright has not been assigned to the Alexandria Library. All requests for permission to publish or quote from manuscripts must be submitted in writing to the Alexandria Library. Permission for publication is given on behalf of the Alexandria Library as the owner of the physical items and is not intended to include or imply permission of the copyright holder, which must also be obtained by the researcher.</dc:rights></record><record xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:dctype="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dc.xsd http://purl.org/dc/terms/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcterms.xsd http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/ http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/dcmitype.xsd http://dublincore.org/schemas/xmls/qdc/2008/02/11/qualifieddc.xsd"><dc:title>[Portrait of Dr. Robert Adeson]</dc:title><dc:date>1980</dc:date><dc:subject>physicians</dc:subject><dc:subject>doctors</dc:subject><dc:subject>Adeson, Robert, M.D.</dc:subject><dc:description>Dr. Robert L. Adeson, Alexandria Hospital.</dc:description><dc:format>1 print : b&amp;w ; 5 x 7 in.</dc:format><dcterms:spatial>Alexandria, Virginia</dcterms:spatial><dc:type>Photograph</dc:type><dc:format>Image</dc:format><dc:identifier>MS332-01-01-002</dc:identifier><dc:rights>Copyright has not been assigned to the Alexandria Library. All requests for permission to publish or quote from manuscripts must be submitted in writing to the Alexandria Library. Permission for publication is given on behalf of the Alexandria Library as the owner of the physical items and is not intended to include or imply permission of the copyright holder, which must also be obtained by the researcher.</dc:rights></record></collection>
```

If it helps, here's the original Python code for cleaning and splitting MODS.  I got it from calhist on github.

```
# Split XML containing many <mods> elements into invidual files
# Modified from script found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36155049/splitting-xml-file-into-multiple-at-given-tags
# by Bill Levay for California Historical Society

import os, lxml.etree as ET
# uncomment below modules if doing MODS cleanup on existing Islandora objects
import codecs, json

output_path = 'C:\\Users\\Staff\\Desktop\\Metadata\\SplitXML\\'

# parse source.xml with lxml
tree = ET.parse('source.xml')

# start cleanup
# remove any element tails
for element in tree.iter():
    element.tail = None

# remove any line breaks or tabs in element text
    if element.text:
        if '\n' in element.text:
            element.text = element.text.replace('\n', '') 
        if '\t' in element.text:
            element.text = element.text.replace('\t', '')

# remove any remaining whitespace
parser = ET.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True, remove_comments=True, recover=True)
treestring = ET.tostring(tree)
clean = ET.XML(treestring, parser)

# remove recursively empty nodes
# found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694091/python-lxml-how-to-remove-empty-repeated-tags
def recursively_empty(e):
   if e.text:
       return False
   return all((recursively_empty(c) for c in e.iterchildren()))

context = ET.iterwalk(clean)
for action, elem in context:
    parent = elem.getparent()
    if recursively_empty(elem):
        parent.remove(elem)

# remove nodes with blank attribute
# for element in clean.xpath(".//*[@*='']"):
#    element.getparent().remove(element)

# remove nodes with attribute "null"
for element in clean.xpath(".//*[@*='null']"):
    element.getparent().remove(element)

# finished cleanup
# write out to intermediate file
with open('clean.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(ET.tostring(clean))
print("XML is now clean")

# parse the clean xml
cleanxml = ET.iterparse('clean.xml', events=('end', ))

###
# uncomment this section if doing MODS cleanup on existing Islandora objects
# getting islandora IDs for existing collections
###
# item_list = []

# json_path = 'C:\\mods\\data.json'

# with codecs.open(json_path, encoding='utf-8') as filename:
#     item_list = json.load(filename)
# filename.close
###

# find the <mods> nodes
for event, elem in cleanxml:
    if elem.tag == '{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}mods':

        # the filenames of the resulting xml files will be based on the <identifier> element
        # edit the specific element or attribute if necessary
        identifier = elem.find('{http://www.loc.gov/mods/v3}identifier[@type="local"]').text
        filename = format(identifier + "_MODS.xml")

        ### 
        # uncomment this section if doing MODS cleanup on existing Islandora objects
        # look through the list of object metadata and get the islandora ID by matching the digital object ID
        ###
        # for item in item_list:
        #     local_ID = item["identifier-type:local"]
        #     islandora_ID = item["PID"]

        #     if identifier == local_ID:
        #         filename = format(islandora_ID + "_MODS.xml")
        ###

        # write out to new file
        with open(output_path+filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n")
            f.write(ET.tostring(elem, pretty_print = True))
        print("Writing", filename)

# remove the intermediate file
os.remove('clean.xml')
print("All done!")
```

Comment: The `record` element is not in the `http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/` namespace (it is in no namespace). Therefore `if elem.tag == '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}record'` does not work.

Comment: I feel dumb now.  HOWEVER, I took out the namespace for 'record' and it's now saying `line 80, in <module>  identifier = elem.find('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}dc:identifier').text  AttributeError: 'nonType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Remove the `dc:` prefix from `elem.find('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}dc:identifier')`. That is incorrect syntax.

Comment: THANK YOU.  You're amazing. Should I comment with your fix?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "comment with your fix". Is everything working now? Should I post an answer?

Comment: Yeah, I was just asking if you'd like me to do it, or if you'd like to do it.  Not sure if anyone else would find it helpful, but it would've helped me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two namespace-related problems:

1. The `record` element is in no namespace. Therefore, you need to change

   ```
   if elem.tag == '{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}record':
   ```

   to

   ```
   if elem.tag == 'record':
   ```
2. `elem.find('{http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/}dc:identifier')` is not correct. The `dc:` bit must be removed.